# How to display Google Maps with both Markers and Polylines?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-polyline

I can create a map that displays Polylines and a map that can display Markers, but I can not get them to show on one map. I need a basic map with two different coloured polylines and custom markers displayed OVER the polylines.

Any examples in HTML for me?

Andre

Comment: what problems are you getting when trying to show both polylines and markers on the same map. please tell us so we could help!

Comment: this shoul not be a problem with. markers and polylines are different.

Comment: Non of the examples I could find on the web showed both Markers and Polylines on one map using basic code. There were some that read XML or JSON files, but I needed a basic file. The Google code example uses a function to create random points but does not show how to just paste a few points.

Answer (score 0):

I finally conquered the problem and got a working solution.

```
function initialize() {
  if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
    var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
    map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl());
    map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
    map.setCenter(new GLatLng(-25.935, 28.17), 10);

    // Add markers to the map

    // Define Icons
    var baseIcon = new GIcon();
    baseIcon.iconSize=new GSize(32,32);
    baseIcon.shadowSize=new GSize(56,32);
    baseIcon.iconAnchor=new GPoint(16,16);
    baseIcon.infoWindowAnchor=new GPoint(16,0);
    var station = new GIcon(baseIcon,  "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pal4/icon57.png", null, "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pal4/icon57s.png");
    var plane   = new GIcon(baseIcon, "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pal2/icon56.png", null, "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pal2/icon56s.png");

    function createMarker(point,html,icon) {
      var marker = new GMarker(point,icon);
      GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
        marker.openInfoWindowHtml(html);
      });
    return marker;
    }

    // OR Tambo
    var point = new GLatLng(-26.131774, 28.231645);
    var marker = createMarker(point,'<div id="infoBox"><a href="http://www.gautrainschedule.co.za/station.php?sid=5&action=custom">OR Tambo<\/a> is located inside OR Tambo International Airport<\/div>', station)
    map.addOverlay(marker);


    // Rhodesfield
    var point = new GLatLng(-26.126582, 28.225250);
    var marker = createMarker(point,'<div id="infoBox"><a href="http://www.gautrainschedule.co.za/station.php?sid=6&action=custom">Rhodesfield Station<\/a> services Kempton Park area, excluding OR Tambo International airport.<\/div>', station)
    map.addOverlay(marker);

    // Marlboro
    var point = new GLatLng(-26.084702, 28.105270);
    var marker = createMarker(point,'<div id="infoBox"><a href="http://www.gautrainschedule.co.za/station.php?sid=7&action=custom">Marlboro Station<\/a> is located close to the N3 highway<\/div>', station)
    map.addOverlay(marker);

    // Sandton
    var point = new GLatLng(-26.107855, 28.058138);
    var marker = createMarker(point,'<div id="infoBox"><a href="http://www.gautrainschedule.co.za/station.php?sid=8&action=custom">Sandton Station<\/a> is located close to major shopping center and other major corporations.<\/div>', station)
    map.addOverlay(marker);


    // Draw East West Route  
    var polyline = new GPolyline([
    new GLatLng(-26.107855, 28.058138),
    new GLatLng(-26.084702, 28.105270),
    new GLatLng(-26.126582, 28.225250),
    new GLatLng(-26.131774, 28.231645)
    ], "#00ff00",8);
    map.addOverlay(polyline);

  }
}

</script>
```

And to display the map use the following html:

```
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 290px; height: 350px"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void setUpMap() {

        // Instantiates a new Polyline object and adds points to define a rectangle
        PolylineOptions rectOptions = new PolylineOptions()
                .add(new LatLng(13.058375, 80.236052))
                .add(new LatLng(13.058792, 80.235837))  // North of the previous point, but at the same longitude
                .add(new LatLng(13.059225, 80.235818))  // Same latitude, and 30km to the west
                .add(new LatLng(13.059973, 80.235799))  // Same longitude, and 16km to the south
                .add(new LatLng(13.060984, 80.235759))
                .add(new LatLng(13.061232, 80.235743))
                .add(new LatLng(13.061331, 80.235713))
                .add(new LatLng(13.061418, 80.235665))
                .add(new LatLng(13.061470, 80.235528))
                .add(new LatLng(13.061514, 80.235144))
                .add(new LatLng(13.061679, 80.234702))
                .add(new LatLng(13.062787, 80.234672))
                .add(new LatLng(13.062747, 80.233774))
                .add(new LatLng(13.062755, 80.233600))
                .add(new LatLng(13.062591, 80.233549))
                .add(new LatLng(13.062473, 80.233519))
                .width(25)
                .color(Color.BLUE)
                .geodesic(true); // Closes the polyline.

// Get back the mutable Polyline
        Polyline polyline = mMap.addPolyline(rectOptions);

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(13.058375, 80.236052)).title("Hostel").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)));
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(13.062451, 80.233247)).title("Bertram Hall").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)));
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(13.061299, 80.234671)).title("Church").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)));

    }
     }
```

this is the polyline and marker code i used and it worked fine for me . change the latlng value according to ur need.